# Making javascript google maps act more "native"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm giving cordova an honest shot (via ionic cli) and it's going pretty well functionally but the UX screams non-native. Here's my current implementation:

[Here's an example from where I got my initial maps code](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uzngt)

**index.html**

```
...
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
...
```

**templates/map.html**

```
...
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
...
```

**MapCtrl**

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    $scope.map = map;
  }
  //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  ionic.Platform.ready(initialize);
});
```

*how I initiate a marker in MapCtrl*

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: $scope.map,
      position: o.getLatLng(),
      icon: {
        url: thumb, // "img/somethumb.png"
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(62, 62), //size
        // origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), //origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 108) //anchor
      }
    });
```

In my journey of making the UX more friendly on better-performance devices every now and again I find a glimmer of something helpful and then it turns out to be a hack that doesn't help much. There has to be some way to get a more native feel out of this code. Here are some issues I would like to smooth over:

- new map images don't load until the user releases ALL touches after a pinch/zoom
- markers do not resize until the user releases ALL touches after a pinch/zoom
- uses bitmap images as opposed to vector (html5 canvas?)

I'm sure there's more to improve but I'm starting small for now. What are some things I can do to make API work with a more native feel?

Answer (score 0):

1. new map images... this behavior is on the desktop not only on mobile. This is to save resources (given that you have done number of native apps you haven't run into this requirement.
2. markers do not resize... this would be considered a nice to have and not necessary, this behavior doesn't hinder the usability of the application. In the end is an application not a game.
3. bitmap vs vector, the application has to support several devices. Why make 2 versions when the bitmap works well? See the browser requirements and limitations of some one that has developed a vector/html5 version http://simplemaps.com/us

Comment: If you look at the google maps app as a standalone application it runs differently (and vector based). I know I won't be able to leverage all the features of the native maps but I'd like to at least get some of the features, you know what I mean?